# How do I check if IP range is in IPV4 and IPV6 CIDR format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cidr

For example, How do I validate that the IP range 192.168.2.0/24 is in IPV4 or IPV6 CIDR format?

Need help modifying:

```
public static bool IsValidIP(string address)
{
    IPAddress ip;
    if (!IPAddress.TryParse(address, out ip)) return false;

    switch (ip.AddressFamily)
    {
        case AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
            if (address.Length > 6 && address.Contains("."))
            {
                string[] s = address.Split('.');
                if (s.Length == 4 && s[0].Length > 0 && s[1].Length > 0 && s[2].Length > 0 && s[3].Length > 0)
                    return true;
            }
            break;
        case AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
            if (address.Contains(":") && address.Length > 15)
                return true;
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIDR always ends with a "/xx", so just knock that off if it exists and parse the stuff before using the `IPAddress` class.

```
using System.Net;

var input = "192.168.2.0/24";
// or
var input = "2345:0425:2CA1:0000:0000:0567:5673:23b5/64";

var segments = input.Split('/');

var isValidIpAddress = IPAddress.TryParse(segments[0], out var parsedAddress);
Console.WriteLine(parsedAddress.AddressFamily);

var isCIDR = segments.Length is 2; // you should also validate segments[1] 
                                   // is an allowed value as well based on
                                   // the IP version.
```

Comment: And if you want to be extra picky, you could check if `xx` is a valid number in the allowed range, ie 0-32 for IPv4 and 0-128 for IPv6

Comment: //IPV4
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;

Comment: //IPV6   if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                   return true;
            }
            return false;

Comment: Would I still need to split the IP using ip.AddressFamily to check if it's IPV4 or IPV6?

Comment: @Chaka [IPAddress.AddressFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily?view=net-7.0) tells you what the version is, v4 or v6. I'm not sure what you mean by "split IP using the property".

Comment: I meant if my input is range = 192.168.2.0/24, can I parse it like this IPAddress.TryParse(range, out ip)?  then follow it up with the code above.

Comment: `IPAddress.TryParse("192.168.2.0/24", out ip)` will fail, you have to remove the `/24` part ...